# Create kubernetes secret for docker registry - Terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

Using `kubectl` we can create `docker registry authentication secret` as follows

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry regsecret \
--docker-server=docker.example.com \
--docker-username=kube \
--docker-password=PW_STRING \
--docker-email=my@email.com \
```

How do i create this `secret` using `terraform`, i saw this [link](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/r/secret.html#example-usage), it has `data`, in the flow of `terraform` the `kubernetes` instance is being created in `azure` and i get the data required from there and i created something like below

```
resource "kubernetes_secret" "docker-registry" {
  metadata {
    name = "registry-credentials"
  }

  data = {
    docker-server = data.azurerm_container_registry.docker_registry_data.login_server
    docker-username = data.azurerm_container_registry.docker_registry_data.admin_username
    docker-password = data.azurerm_container_registry.docker_registry_data.admin_password
  }


}
```

It seems that it is wrong as the images are not being pulled. What am i missing here.

Comment: Is the “sign in as Admin“ flag in your acr set to true? Why not use a service principal and create a Pull permission for the aks. That's the recommanded config.

Comment: Sorry i have never used it, can you please direct me to that.

Comment: I added an answer to describe how to use terraform to grant access

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest creating a `azurerm_role_assignement` to give aks access to the acr:

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "aks_sp_acr" {
  scope                = azurerm_container_registry.acr.id
  role_definition_name = "AcrPull"
  principal_id         = var.service_principal_obj_id

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks,
    azurerm_container_registry.acr
  ]
}
```

**Update**

You can create the service principal in the azure portal or with az cli and use client_id, client_secret and object-id in terraform.

Get Client_id and Object_id by running `az ad sp list --filter "displayName eq '<name>'"`. The secret has to be created in the `Certificates & secrets` tab of the service principal. See this guide: https://pixelrobots.co.uk/2018/11/first-look-at-terraform-and-the-azure-cloud-shell/

Just set all three as variable, eg for obj_id:

```
variable "service_principal_obj_id" {
   default = "<object-id>"
}
```

Now use the credentials with aks:

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks" {

  ...

  service_principal {
    client_id     = var.service_principal_app_id
    client_secret = var.service_principal_password
  }

  ...

}
```

And set the object id in the acr as described above.

**Alternative**

You can create the service principal with terraform (only works if you have the necessary permissions).  https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azuread/r/service_principal.html combined with a `random_password` resource:

```
resource "azuread_application" "aks_sp" {
  name                       = "somename"
  available_to_other_tenants = false
  oauth2_allow_implicit_flow = false
}

resource "azuread_service_principal" "aks_sp" {
  application_id = azuread_application.aks_sp.application_id

  depends_on = [
    azuread_application.aks_sp
  ]
}

resource "azuread_service_principal_password" "aks_sp_pwd" {
  service_principal_id = azuread_service_principal.aks_sp.id
  value                = random_password.aks_sp_pwd.result
  end_date             = "2099-01-01T01:02:03Z"

  depends_on = [
    azuread_service_principal.aks_sp
  ]
}
```

You need to assign the role "Conributer" to the sp and can use it directly in aks / acr.

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "aks_sp_role_assignment" {
  scope                = var.subscription_id
  role_definition_name = "Contributor"
  principal_id         = azuread_service_principal.aks_sp.id

  depends_on = [
    azuread_service_principal_password.aks_sp_pwd
  ]
}
```

Use them with aks:

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks" {

  ...

  service_principal {
    client_id     = azuread_service_principal.aks_sp.app_id
    client_secret = azuread_service_principal_password.aks_sp_pwd.value
  }

  ...

}
```

and the role assignment:

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "aks_sp_acr" {
  scope                = azurerm_container_registry.acr.id
  role_definition_name = "AcrPull"
  principal_id         = azuread_service_principal.aks_sp.object_id

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks,
    azurerm_container_registry.acr
  ]
}
```

**Update secret example**

```
resource "random_password" "aks_sp_pwd" {
  length = 32
  special = true
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, `principal_id         = var.service_principal_obj_id` where does this come from

Comment: after this, in `kubernetes` how do i handle the secret

Comment: If you need further help, please ask, if my answer helped you, please consider upvoting/accepting :)

Comment: sorry, there was a power cut, i tried this beautiful solution, but the kubernetes still showing the error, should i do anything on the `secrets` in kubernetes?

Comment: The client secret is created with terraform with resource random_password https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/random/r/password.html just name it ``aks_sp_pwd ``. Terraform creates a secret and manages it. You don't need to know the value for Kubernetes itself. Not sure if this is your exact question.

Comment: I added an example, hopefullly that solves all issues.

Comment: Amazingly explained beautiful answer. Accepted as answer.

Comment: is it same for other services as well? what if i want to have a `secret` for `azure storage`

Comment: Yeah sure, but make sure to create a new one for every resource to prevent security issues.

Answer (score 27):

If you run following command

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry regsecret \
--docker-server=docker.example.com \
--docker-username=kube \
--docker-password=PW_STRING \
--docker-email=my@email.com
```

It will create a secret like following

```
$ kubectl get secrets regsecret -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: eyJhdXRocyI6eyJkb2NrZXIuZXhhbXBsZS5jb20iOnsidXNlcm5hbWUiOiJrdWJlIiwicGFzc3dvcmQiOiJQV19TVFJJTkciLCJlbWFpbCI6Im15QGVtYWlsLmNvbSIsImF1dGgiOiJhM1ZpWlRwUVYxOVRWRkpKVGtjPSJ9fX0=
kind: Secret
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2020-06-01T18:31:07Z"
  name: regsecret
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "42304"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets/regsecret
  uid: 59054483-2789-4dd2-9321-74d911eef610
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

If we decode `.dockerconfigjson` we will get

```
{"auths":{"docker.example.com":{"username":"kube","password":"PW_STRING","email":"my@email.com","auth":"a3ViZTpQV19TVFJJTkc="}}}
```

So, how can we do that using terraform?

I created a file `config.json` with following data

```
{"auths":{"${docker-server}":{"username":"${docker-username}","password":"${docker-password}","email":"${docker-email}","auth":"${auth}"}}}
```

Then in `main.tf` file

```
resource "kubernetes_secret" "docker-registry" {
  metadata {
    name = "regsecret"
  }

  data = {
    ".dockerconfigjson" = "${data.template_file.docker_config_script.rendered}"
  }

  type = "kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson"
}


data "template_file" "docker_config_script" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/config.json")}"
  vars = {
    docker-username           = "${var.docker-username}"
    docker-password           = "${var.docker-password}"
    docker-server             = "${var.docker-server}"
    docker-email              = "${var.docker-email}"
    auth                      = base64encode("${var.docker-username}:${var.docker-password}")
  }
}
```

then run

```
$ terraform apply
```

This will generate same secrets. Hope it will helps

Comment: Thanks for your efforts and reply, this is also a right answer.